# Appcelerator : Fonts are not recognized from SDK 5.2.0.GA

Tags: ios, fonts, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My apps no longer recognize the fonts files with **SDK >= 5.2.0.GA**.

With **SDK <= 5.1.2.GA** the are no problem

[image]

Reading the docs i didn't find anything related to this problem, or am i wrong?

- [SDK 5.2.1.GA docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+SDK+5.2.1.GA+Release+Note)
- [SDK 5.2.0.GA docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Titanium+SDK+5.2.0+Release+Note)

---

**TiApp.xml**

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UIAppFonts</key>
            <array>
                <string>/fonts/icons.ttf</string>
            </array>
            ....
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

**Font directory**

[image]

**Example of icon**

```
var IconicFont = require('/icon/IconicFont');
var Icons = new IconicFont({
    font : '/icon/ListIcons'
});

var myBtn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    height : 50,
    width : 50,
    color : 'white',
    font : {
        fontSize : 30,
        fontFamily : Icons.fontfamily
    },
    title : Icons.icon("nameicon"),
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    verticalAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
});
```

**IconicFont.js**

```
function IconicFont(params) {
    params = params || {};

    this._font = require(params.font);
}

Object.defineProperties(IconicFont.prototype, {
    font: {
        set: function(param){
            this._font = require(param);
        },
        get: function(){
            return this._font;
        }
    },
    fontfamily: {
        get: function(){
            return this._font.fontfamily;
        }
    }
});

IconicFont.prototype.icon = function(param){
    var result = [];

    if (!Array.isArray(param)) {
        param = [param];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        result.push(String.fromCharCode(this._font.charcode[param[i]]));
    }

    return result.join('');
};

module.exports = IconicFont;
```

**ListIcons.js**

```
exports.fontfamily = 'FontName';
exports.charcode = {
   'image':0xf11a,
   '.....':......
};
```

Comment: Surely the Appcelerator forums would be a better place for your question?

Comment: SO is the new Appcelerator forum. http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/01/embracing-stack-overflow-for-appcelerator-community-support/

Comment: Can you add some code? Are you sure that you are using the correct postscript name into the fontFamily property?

Comment: The code is always the same, with the SDK 5.1.2 works with higher SDK not.

Comment: I use some icon font and it works on 5.2.1 and below, so sharing your code, the font you use and your file structure would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/platform/iphone/fonts is a really weird place, the [appcelerator docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts) tell you to place them in /app/assets/[android][iphone]/fonts, try to place them here.

Comment: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Custom_Fonts-section-29004935_CustomFonts-Usingacustomfont(Classicapplication)

Comment: It is still the wrong directory for a non alloy project, it is /Resources/iphone/fonts, not /platform/iphone/fonts.

Comment: indeed, font file should be placed inside Resources directory. I'm not placing mine inside iPhone folder, only in Resources

Comment: @CarlosHenriqueLustosa if you don't need to deliver different fonts to different platform (eg, a font for android and a font for iOS) than yes, it is correct to place them directly in /Resources/fonts.